# More actions in Zend Rest Controller apart from the default actions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-rest

I know that REST API can be implemented using Zend_Rest_Controller and it has 5 abstract methods indexAction, getAction, postAction,putAction,deleteAction to perform return, create, update , etc...

My question is, can I have more API fictions with in a controller apart from these default functions to perform various type of operations?.

Eg:

**indexAction** - returns a list of available books,

**searchAction** - returns a list of books based on search criterion. 
(I know it can be done in the indexAction with some parameters but then the code will look more complicated, I need to avoid that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom action methods in your controller. Although you're extending the abstract class Zend_Rest_Controller, as long as you define those 5 abstract methods (the ones you've already mentioned), you're free to customise the rest of your class.

The only similar method you might look into is the [`getAction()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Rest/Zend_Rest_Controller.html). This expects a parameter with the name of ID and will retrieve a record based on the primary key.

---

You'd probably have to define your routing in a configuration file:

```
routes.archive.route = "search/:keyword"
routes.archive.defaults.controller = books
routes.archive.defaults.action = search
routes.archive.defaults.year = "Hamlet"
routes.archive.reqs.year = "\s+"
```

And then you need to feed these configuration options into your Router:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini', 'production');
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
```

Read [Zend's documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest) for a more in-depth tutorial.

Comment: Lest's say I write an action called searchAction, How the Rest controller will identify it as a HTTP GET method?